# RoR differences between :url, :action, :method in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

There might be answers in documentation, but i don't seem to find good answers.
So among the three :url, :action, :method, what are their differences when used in form_for in Rails?

Answer (score 35):

Difference between `:url`, `:action` and `:method`

**:url**

If you want to submit your form for any particular controller, any particular action and want to pass some extra parameter (use action that define in controller that you pass on controller )

*for example*

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => {:controller => "your-controller-name", :action => "your-action-name"} do |f| %>
```

In the above code the form is submitted to that controller(that you pass on url) and goto that (you pass on action) action. it will take defaults to the current action.

now suppose you want to pass extra parameter then **for example**

```
form_for @post, :url => { :action => :update, :type => @type, :this => @currently_editing } do |f| ...
```

you can pass extra parameter like `:type => @type`

so `:url` is The URL the form is submitted to. It takes the same fields you pass to url_for or link_to. In particular you may pass here a named route directly as well.

---

**:action**

```
 form_for @post, :url => { :action => :update, :type => @type, :this => @currently_editing } do |f| ...
```

In the above example we pass `:action` if we want to submit the form in different action then we pass `:action` and `your-action-name` the form is post to that action

---

**:method**

method is used for which method you want to pass for that action. There are several methods like `put`,`post`,`get` ...

*for example*

```
form_for @post, :url => post_path(@post), :method => :put, ....
```

In the above `form_for` we pass `:method => :put` when this form is submit it will use `put` method

Answer (score 13):

form_for is basically used on object. For example:

```
      <% form_for @person do |f| %>
       ...
      <% end %>
```

When you click submit it will go to default action like from :new to :create, :edit => :update. If you want to specify your own action then you have to use :url and :method is used to force to post or get. For example:

```
      <% form_for @person :url => {:action => "my_action"}, :method => "post" do |f| %>
       ...
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Need a comma after @person in the second block. Like this, <% form_for @@person, :url

Answer (score 3):

URL:

Url is the path where your form data should go.
whatever you write inside the :url symbol is considered as the path where your data should go when u click a submit button in the form.

Action:

Action is the method in your controller, in your form_for @user (where @user is a object of User model), if you say :action => create then it sumbit the data to users_controller 'create' function (def create).
You will mention this inside :url to tell that the data should go to the specifiled action.

Method:

Is http method, there are 'get', 'post', 'update', 'patch' and 'delete' method. You can learn about this in google.