# UrlGenerationError for login page Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I am trying to create a login page.  I am following [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-ii/).  However I have gotten stuck with the following error when trying to access my sessions/login page.  I am using Rails 4.1.  I looked at other answers for questions similar to this on S.O. but I was unable to find anything that seemed to relate.  This was my error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Sessions#login
No route matches {:action=>"login_attempt", :controller=>"sessions"}
```

And the line that is highlighted is:

```
    <%= form_tag(:action => 'login_attempt') do %>
```

This is my login page template:

```
<% @page_title = "Foos-Tracker | Login" -%>
<div class= "Sign_Form">
  <h1>Log in</h1>
  <%= form_tag(:action => 'login_attempt') do %>
    <p>Username or Email:</br> <%= text_field_tag(:username_or_email) %></p>
    <p>Password:</br> <%= password_field_tag :login_password %></p>
    <%= submit_tag("Log In") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user, :only => [:home, :profile, :setting]
  before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:login, :login_attempt]

  def login
    #Login Form
  end

  def login_attempt
    authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email],params[:login_password])
    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Wow Welcome again, you logged in as #{authorized_user.username}"
      redirect_to(:action => 'home')
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Invalid Username or Password"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
      render "login"
    end
  end

end
```

And my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/login'
  get 'sessions/home'
  get 'sessions/profile'
  get 'sessions/setting'
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'users/new'

  resources :users

  root 'welcome#index'
```

end

Any ideas / help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your route from `login` to `login_attempt`, if you already have `login` action defined then add another route with name `login_attempt`

Comment: Yes, this seemed to work as well (with action).  Prob. the correct way to actually do it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is that :action isn't the correct syntax anymore.  Had to change it to :method

Comment: can you do what I suggested, I am away from my work PC and need to know what is different about action and method that resolved the issue, as far as I understand I see a missing route.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576745/ror-differences-between-url-action-method-in-form-for) explains it, not sure how it made it a 'get' request to your controller though....