# How to retrieve the current URL within a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to retrieve the full URL of my site (including the https://) in a controller in Ruby. I need it to fit in the following code:

```
url = ""
uri = URI::parse(url)
id = uri.path.split('/')[2]
```

Thanks.

Comment: use request.url to get current url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out with some help and debugging. Because I was requesting the URL within a class that was creating a new object in the database, I had to use `request.referrer`:

```
url = request.referrer
uri = URI::parse(url)
id = uri.path.split('/')[2]
```

And because my URL was like "https://www.example.com/room/4", the **id** returned a value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `request.original_url`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Comment: It returned a nil value

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve the id of a url thats not the way to do it. Something like this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code is the rails approach. Otherwise, check what does your split returns

Comment: I already have that same id going to a separate place, though. Is it allowed to use the same for two? (such as `get "room/:id" => "pages#room"` and `"get room/:id" => "messages#create"`)

Comment: You can use the same route, but HTTP verb has to be different. If you are creating a message, the best way to do it is `post "room/:id/messages" => "messages#create"`. Using post is the standard way to create a resource, and `/messages` to point out which resource are you creating using the room id

Comment: So I manually went into routes.rb and added `post 'room/:id/messages' => 'messages#create'` along with a variety of other needed routes. However, when I submit my form, it redirects to `/messages` and gives the error **_No route matches [POST] "/messages"_**. I feel like I'm getting closer.

Comment: You should change the form url. Idk if you are using simple form or `form_for`, maybe you should check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578844/5379362

Answer (score 1):

As Fede said, you can use in your controller `request.original_url`. Also, if you have some ajax in your view you can pass it as data to your model and after to your controller with `window.location.href` in the JS.

Comment: It seems strange that it will not work in my controller. Is there some sort of gem I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of rails do u have? try `rails -v`

Comment: Currently running 4.2.5

Comment: I guess `request.url` does not work too. Are you using some other framework?

Comment: So I analyzed the problem. It turns out that it returns the url `/messages`. Is there a way to return the url of the page before that?